# Root.plist app settings missing when debugging

Tags: debugging, plist, xamarin.ios

I have created a settings bundle and Root.plist.  When I run my app using the Release|iPhoneSimulator build I can see and edit my settings in the "Settings app" just fine, as expected.

However when I run my app in Debug|iPhoneSimulation mode my settings are gone and replaced by the Debugger Settings.  Is there a way to keep my original Root.plist settings intack while debugging??

I must be doing something stupid because I can't find any references to anyone else having this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a case sensitivity issue.

MonoDevelop merges the debug settings into your settings files, if it finds a file called  Settings.bundle/Root.plist marked as Content in the project, but this check is case sensitive.

If it does not find this file - for example your settings file is cased differently - MD will simply create a new settings file, but the Apple case-insensitive filesystem will consider the filenames to be the same, so it'll end up overwriting yours in the app bundle.

Comment: In my case the folder is named "Settings.bundle" and the file is "Root.plist".  It is marked as "Content" and "Always Copy".

Comment: This is what my root plist looks like if I just copy it out as a text file....
{
 PreferenceSpecifiers = (
  {
   Title = "Optional Title";
   Type = PSGroupSpecifier;
  },
  {
   Type = PSTextFieldSpecifier;
   Title = ImageServer;
   Key = imageServer;
   "AutocapitalizationType" = None;
   AutocorrectionType = No;
  },
  {
   Type = PSTextFieldSpecifier;
   Title = Port;
   Key = port;
  },
 );
}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the examples I've been using to figure out how to do this are bogus.

To resolve the issue I deleted the Root.plist and then re-added it by doing a Add..New File...Property List.  Once I added my custom settings to this plist everything started working.

So if you see examples (such as this one, http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/08/monotouch-settingsbundle.html) where they are telling you to manually create an xml file and then rename it to Root.plist, don't do this.  It doesn't work.

Comment: Also, it is not necessary to set "Copy to output directory" to "Always copy" as I have read many times.  Just leave it set to "Do not copy."

Comment: And set the build action to "Content".

Comment: There is still an issue however... Now that my settings are showing up in the settings app, my application can not access them.  Always returns a null.  I have downloaded and tried other demo apps that use settings and have the same result.  So either something is messed up on Monotouch or the 4.2 update broke something.  I have no idea.